# File Copy Options Not Recognised When Using Files.copy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a Groovy script to copy a file which works fine until I try to add the option to copy the file attributes as well, i.e. to preserve the timestamps.

This works:

```
import java.nio.file.*

def fileEx = new File(/Y:\Documents\Test File.txt/)
def fileDest = new File(/Y:\Documents\Test File copied with Groovy and Nio.txt/)

def fileExPath = fileEx.toPath()
def fileDestPath = fileDest.toPath()

Files.copy(fileExPath, fileDestPath)
```

But this fails:

```
import java.nio.file.*

def fileEx = new File(/Y:\Documents\Test File.txt/)
def fileDest = new File(/Y:\Documents\Test File copied with Groovy and Nio.txt/)

def fileExPath = fileEx.toPath()
def fileDestPath = fileDest.toPath()

Files.copy(fileExPath, fileDestPath, COPY_ATTRIBUTES)
```

with the error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: COPY_ATTRIBUTES for class: temp
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: COPY_ATTRIBUTES for class: temp
    at temp.run(temp.groovy:9)
```

I've tried putting COPY_ATTRIBUTES in single quotes and double quotes, but that doesn't help.  Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need reference to the enum class:

```
Files.copy(fileExPath, fileDestPath, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES)
```

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed the problem.

Do you know why none of the code examples I looked at require the reference to the enum class?  Have I omitted an import statement or something?

Comment: you could do a static import of the StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, that would have worked too